# Google Apps Script issue with oauth2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I have a Google Apps Scripts built that is successfully leveraging the My Business API to pull Google reviews from multiple locations and send them to Google Sheets.

The issue I am facing is that every time I run the script, I get the following prompt in the exeuction log:[execution log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S91a8.png)

Basically the prompt gives me a URL to copy and paste into a new window, login to my email, and then it authorizes me.

I then re-run the same script and it will successfully execute.

**The problem**** is that I can't have this script run automatically each day, because it requires me to copy that URL and paste it every time to authorize.

I had added a .setExpirationMinutes to 100 years in hopes this would basically keep me authorized and not have to repeat those steps (see image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz9Ho.png) but, it's not working lol.

Anyone else know what I can do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add code and logs as text, not as images.